# Obtener último registro de BBDD con Entity Framework en C#

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, entity-framework

Me encuentro rellenando los campos de una tabla con datos que he recogido de un excel, uno de los campos es `ID_C`, el cual quiero rellenar obteniendo el último `ID_C`registrado en BBDD y sumarle uno, esto lo quiero hacer en mi código de C#.

No sé como puedo obtener el número del último `ID_C`para poder sumarle uno y que el nuevo registro se guarde con ese resultado.

```
 public bool AddCust(List<REGISTRO_CARGA> listaDoc)
    {
        bool ok = false;

        using (ABCEntities contexto = new ABCEntities())
        {
            using (var transaction = contexto.Database.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable))
            {
                try
                {
                    REGISTRO_CARGA newdoc;

                    foreach (REGISTRO_CARGA d in listaDoc)
                    {
                        newdoc = new REGISTRO_CARGA_()
                        {
                            LOCALIZACION = d.LOCALIZACION,
                            UBICACION = d.UBICACION,
                            USUARIO = d.USUARIO,
                            //ID_C= d.ID_C

                        };

                        contexto.REGISTRO_CARGA.Add(newdoc);

                    }
                    contexto.SaveChanges();

                    //falta hacer BACKUP BBDD
                    foreach (REGISTRO_CARGA) ;

                        contexto.SaveChanges();

                    transaction.Commit();
                    ok = true;

                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    eLog.RegistrarError(ex);
                    transaction.Rollback();
                    ok = false;
                }

            }


        }
```

Comment: `ID_C` no es un campo autoincremental?

Comment: no, no lo puse como autoincremental porque necesito que sea así porque va relacionado con otras tablas.

Comment: Quizás este enlace puede ayudarte o servirte de referencia: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5212751/how-can-i-get-id-of-inserted-entity-in-entity-framework ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para obtener el ultimo registro usando `entity framework` usas el `Max()`, o algo como esto

```
int lastId = contexto.REGISTRO_CARGA.Max(x=> x.ID_C);
```

a ese valor le puede sumar uno y lo asignas al insertar

```
foreach (REGISTRO_CARGA d in listaDoc)
{
    int lastId = contexto.REGISTRO_CARGA.Max(x=> x.ID_C);

    newdoc = new REGISTRO_CARGA_()
    {
        LOCALIZACION = d.LOCALIZACION,
        UBICACION = d.UBICACION,
        USUARIO = d.USUARIO,
        ID_C = lastId 
    };

    //resto codigo
```

en cada iteracion obtienes el proximo Id

saludos